# Circular Image distorting with Auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have my storyboard set to 4.7" while I work. When I run my app on the iP6 simulator my circular UIImageView looks nice and round. Like so:

[image]

However, I'm experiencing distortion with my circular UIImageView when I run the app in all the other simulators

Here's iP5:

[image]

and here's iP6+:

[image]

Here's the code i'm using to round the UIImageView:

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

The size of the UIImageView is adjusting correctly, just the roundness gets all funky as you can see. Here are the constraints I have set just in case:

1:1 ratio, align center x to view, align top to view = 15, align bottom to view = -100

The image starts as a perfect square, so I figured that with the 1:1 ratio set it would always stay circular with the code I used...what am I doing wrong here? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and your code is 100% correct, the problem is with the autolayout and these constraints:

> align top to view = 15, align bottom to view = -100

You can't align to top view and to bottom view because the screen size changes. What you can do is only align to top and find another constraint to maintain the size. What works for me with profile pictures is having a size constraint.

Before, with up and bottom constraints:
[image]

After, with up and fixed width constraints:
[image]

Comment: Right, so you're saying get rid of bottom and add a width and height constraint. That would work, but the container it lives in is small, and i need the size to adjust. When it drops down to iPhone 5 i get overlapping if i set width height constraints, as the image then appears much too big.

Comment: Can you post a Screenshot so I can better see what constraints we could use?

Comment: Basic 4 side constraints are available. The profile image is 140x140, and it sits in a table cell that's 220 in height and it adjusts with auto layout to keep it's aspect ratio. That's why i can't set an absolute width and height for the profile image because that 220 becomes much less when the app adjust for say an iPhone 5. I need the circle to adjust size, too, to keep things in balance.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put that code?

The `cornerRadius` will not change when the view size changes. You need to update it (to match the view's size) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in your VC, or at the end of `layoutSubviews` in your view class.

Comment: it lives in a custom cell in a tableViewController. So the actual code is like cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius...

Comment: so it's getting loaded in the cellForRowAtIndexPath func

Answer (score 0):

try this definitely it will work.
**swift** code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    perform(#selector(self.setCircleForImage(_:)), with: pickedImage, afterDelay: 0)
}


 @objc func setCircleForImage(_ imageView : UIImageView){
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = pickedImage.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

> UIImage must maintain 1:1 aspect ratio